# Send xlsx data in apis with Axlsx::Package and convert the received response string again to Axlsx::Package class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, api, xlsx, axlsx

I am working on api's which returns the data created in xlsx format with the following code

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx do
        p  = Axlsx::Package.new
        wb = p.workbook
        wb.add_worksheet(name: "MyWorkSheet") do |sheet|
          sheet.add_row ["Column1", "Column2", "Column2"]
          @myData.each do |locale|
            sheet.add_row [locale.column1, locale.column2, locale.column3]
          end
        end
        send_data Base64.encode64(p.to_stream.read), type: "application/xlsx", filename: "myfile.xlsx"
      end
```

p is of class `Axlsx::Package`

On the web end i receive the following response

```
response => <Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

Now I want to create xlsx file from this response body

I have decoded the body of response with the following code and received the data

```
decoded_data = Base64.decode64(response.body)
```

But decoded_data is of `String` class.

My problem is that

How can i convert this `decoded_data` to again `Axlsx::Package` class and save/export it in xlsx file?

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed the raw source of the xlsx file, all you need is:

```
File.open('filename.xlsx', 'w') {|f| f.write(decoded_data) }
```